# How to connect or set a specifig schema in LIBGDA database browser?

Tags: browser, database, postgresql

I've here a PostgreSQL based database, with a schema and some tables inside it. When I use *psql* I must put the schema name in front of every statement:

```
SELECT * FROM schemahere.tablehere;
```

Or is set the search path like this:

```
SET search_path = webmka;
```

That works both. But within the database-browser of LIBGDA I can't see the schema itself (why?) and I can't fire the SET command. Can I use the connection options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If LIBGDA doesn't understand schemas, you can work around this with one of the following:

- `ALTER DATABASE the_database SET search_path = webmka, public;`
- `ALTER USER libgda_user SET search_path = webmka, public;`

to make the `search_path` persistently associated with either the database of interest (1st option) or a user dedicated to libgda (2nd option).

Comment: Thank you. It seems libgda UI itself can handle schemas (set the search_path in connection properties), the problem was the following missing statement "GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schemahere TO userhere;" + sufficient rights on tables itselt. Hint "fetch metadata" in libgda database browser can maybe help

Comment: @PeterWeber Thankyou for following up. It sounds like you were probably connecting with a different user via libgda than when testing in psql, right? Otherwise the rights should've been the same for both.

Comment: You're right (psql = postgres, libgda = userforspecialpurpose).

Comment: Yep, so your `psql` test wasn't really the same as your libgda test, which is why you didn't get the same results testing manually. Glad to confirm that.